# Export cassandra keyspace to .cql file

Tags: cassandra

I need to export my keyspace to a .cql file. I have tried the  cqlsh -e "DESC keyspace demo" > dump.cql command but that doesnt work and i need the Insert scripts also.

I also tried the COPY command but it doesnt serve my purpose. I also want to be able to import from the cql file.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me on a 3.0 install:

```
cqlsh -e 'DESCRIBE keyspace demo' > dump.cql    - gets the create syntax
cqlsh < dump.cql    - creates the keyspace on a new cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sstable2json and json2sstable cassandra tools

Check out Datastax [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTable2JsonNew.html) on the same and [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsJson2SSTable.html) too

```
Usage: sstable2json [-f outfile] <sstable> [-k key [-k key [...]]]
Usage: json2sstable -K keyspace -c column_family <json> <sstable>
```

Desc Keyspace will export only keyspace schema.
If you want to export data also you have to use following utility.

Comment: I am not sure about this but there is no execute called json2sstable or json2sstable in my cassandra bin directory. From where are you running this?

Comment: which version of cassandra are you using

Comment: I am using 3.0 version

Comment: I also checked the same in 2.1. It is not available there too

Comment: it is in tools/bin cassandra 2.1